# how to stop printing history of word document like filename, directory etc

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

When I take printout of any word document, automatically document history get printed like Filename, Directory, Template etc. after every word document. How to stop this additional printing?

Answer (score 0):

Office 2007 is ancient, but I presume it is the same as more recent versions of Office.

Go to Preferences/Options >> Output (or Print) options.
There should be some check-boxes to include some particular things in the printout. Like Drawing Objects, Hidden fields and "Document Properties".

It is probably that last one "Document Properties" that you want to disable.

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved

Comment: @kalpana: If this answer was helpful, better mark it as accepted (tick the V sign).